# Customer product range

Tags: checkout, customer

I'm looking for a way to create 'product ranges' for specific customers.
It should either be able to limit the products a certain customer can view and order, or add a custom sorting to the order in which the products are displayed in a category. But per customer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Erik, Magento is not made to do customer based things. So I would think about a customer_group solution. Beside this you can implement everything with a couple of event handlers. If you are more specific, we can give you a more specific answer :)

Comment: This is quite broad in scope. Best to think in terms of customer groups as noted. If you are getting down to individual sorts or lists per customer, that is a complex requirement.